# Return local String as an Option<&str>

Tags: rust

I want to write a function that receives a `&str` argument and returns `Option<&str>`. I wrote this:

```
fn f(text: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    if // some condition {
        return None;
    }

    let mut res = String::new();
    // write something into res.

    // return res
    Some(&res[..])
}
```

but I get an error:

> `res` does not live long enough.

What is the best solution to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot return a `&str` that points into a local `String` variable. Doing that would mean that you just returned a dangling pointer, as the `String` (`res`, in your code) is destroyed when the function returns.

The best way to fix your problem is probably to return a `Option<String>`, i.e. return the owned string instead of a string slice. Adapting your code, you might end up with something like this:

```
fn f(text: &str) -> Option<String> {
    if // some condition {
        return None;
    }

    let mut res = String::new();
    // write something into res.

    Some(res)
}
```

Comment: Why not just `Some(res)`?

Comment: @DK. Yeah, that made no sense. I read the `[..]` as pseudo-code for "some unspecified slice into that string", instead of its literal meaning for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: fjh, ok, i will change my return type, thanks a lot!